# Mandrill emails stuck in queued

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, mandrill, back4app

I managed to figure out how to send emails via Mandrill and Parse Cloud Code with Back4App. When checking the API logs for Mandrill I see the following:

```
Full Request
{
    "message": {
        "text": "asdf Email Test",
        "subject": "adsf Email Test",
        "from_email": "no-reply@asdf.ca",
        "from_name": "Site",
        "to": [
            {
                "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
                "name": "Martin",
                "type": "to"
            }
        ],
        "headers": {
            "Reply-To": "no-reply@adsf.ca"
        }
    },
    "async": false,
    "ip_pool": "Main Pool",
    "send_at": "2018-03-13T17:14:41.645Z",
    "key": "oc7ueJMLRGgaEDrjhk5DBg"
}


Full Response
[
    {
        "email": "myemail@gmail.com",
        "status": "queued",
        "_id": "7c28e80e4de1405f93d1d096600128d4",
        "reject_reason": null
    }
]
```

It seems as if the code is executing properly but the response body indicates that the email is queued. I decided to wait 24 hours and nothing has changed. I sent some more test emails and I get the same result. Basically, the emails are not sending. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

apparently for Mandrill work with Back4App you need to setup a own domain, and it looks like you're using a Gmail email address. Therefore, it is recommended to use SendGrid in this case :)